# wp htaccess redirect 301 index.html to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the same problem with here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/help-pointing-to-wordpressindexhtml-does-not-work, but this is not resolve and closed topic.

The site has a static html live site and transferred in wordpress CMS, so in SEO matter the index.html is needed to be redirect in wp homepage `http://mysite.com/dev/`, but when I redirect it using `redirect 301` the browser flash an error (`The page isn't redirecting properly`). And please note: I am using **custom permalink plugin** to include .html extension in inerpages.

I know that many people here have a sufficient experience, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all manual .htaccess modifications and install redirection plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/.

Go to Tools>Redirection and enter a new reidrection

Source URL: /myblog/index.html
Target URL: /myblog/

Answer (score 1):

I still try the answer here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/help-pointing-to-wordpressindexhtml-does-not-work, I find out that it is working I just forgot to remove the line that I first try.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ /dev/ [NC,R=301,L]#this line do the tricks

    RewriteBase /dev/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]

</IfModule>`

so if I transfer the file in root I will just remove the dev/.

Answer (score 0):

try these:

php:

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.site.com/dev/" );
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^yoursite.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/dev/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: oh I forgot to note this, I'm working the wordpress version in my dev folder but if is all set, I will transfer it in root.